# Removing Duplicate Value in Rest Api

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, sharepoint-rest-api, duplicate

I have a small requirement where in i need to remove the duplicate values from the array that i am getting.

**Overview**
In the below code, what i am trying to do is to get top 1000 employee names(Should Cost Modeler People Picker Field) through REST API from List A and appending those values in LIST B Drop down. But as i get all the names through REST API there are many duplicate values in the array.

What i would like to do is to remove the duplicate values and then append the values to drop down.

//Get the employee names

```
function getAllEmployeeNames(){
var results;
$.ajax({
    url: _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Should Cost Projects')/items?$select=Should_x0020_Cost_x0020_Modeler/Title&$expand=Should_x0020_Cost_x0020_Modeler/Id&$top=500",
    type: "GET",
    async:false,
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    },
    success: function (data) {
        if(data.d.results.length>0){
            results=data.d.results;
        }
    },
    error: function (data) {
    //alert("Error");
    }
});
return results;
  }
```

// To Append the Employee Name to drop down on form load.

```
var employeeName=$("input[title^='Employee Name']").val();
$("input[title^='Employee Name']").hide();
$("input[title^='Employee Name']").after("<select id='EmployeeField' class='ms-RadioText'><option value=''></option></select>");
$("input[title^='Project Name']").hide();
$("input[title^='Project Name']").after("<select id='ProjectField' class='ms-RadioText'><option value=''></option></select>");
var allEmployeeNames=getAllEmployeeNames();
console.log(allEmployeeNames);


    $.each(allEmployeeNames,function(i,employee){
    $.each(employee.Should_x0020_Cost_x0020_Modeler.results,function(j,item){
        if(employeeName==item.Title){
            $("#EmployeeField").append("<option selected='selected' value='"+item.Title+"'>"+item.Title+"</option>");
        }else{
            if(item.Title!=undefined){
                $("#EmployeeField").append("<option value='"+item.Title+"'>"+item.Title+"</option>");
            }           
        }   
    });         
});
```

// the code that i am using to remove duplicates but it is not working.

```
$(allEmployeeNames).each(function() {
    $(this).siblings('[value="'+ $(this).val() +'"]').remove();
});
```

Please help me solve this problem.

Thanks

Comment: What is the result you are getting? How can you use $(this) on looping an array of objects (result from SharePoint REST)?

Comment: Please try solution given in here as answer. Don't forget to use `$top` as query option.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25744763/get-distinct-data-of-sharepoint-list-using-rest-api

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is, find the unique values after getting results from your first REST call(After getting all possible employee names).

Then find the unique employees in your array and after getting unique values, append to dropdown. There are many ways to find the unique values in your array:

1. Using Plain Javascript.
2. Using JQuery.
3. Using plugins like lodash.js or underscore.js

You can find more details to get unique values from your array, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15125920/how-to-get-distinct-values-from-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript).

Comment: I get what you are trying to say but i cannot do it that is why i have posted a question here

Answer (score 0):

I see you have employee details in an arrays inside the results you get from SharePoint REST. For your case, you need to create a temporary array which will store the unique values of employee name. Check the code below:

```
var tempEmployeesArray = [];  

$.each(allEmployeeNames,function(i,employee){
  $.each(employee.Should_x0020_Cost_x0020_Modeler.results,function(j,item){
            if(employeeName==item.Title){
                if(tempEmployeesArray.indexOf(item.Title) < 0){
                    //code if duplicate not found
                    tempEmployeesArray.push(item.Title);
                    $("#EmployeeField").append("<option selected='selected' value='"+item.Title+"'>"+item.Title+"</option>");
                }

            }else{
                if(item.Title!=undefined){
                    if(tempEmployeesArray.indexOf(item.Title) < 0){
                        //code if duplicate not found
                        tempEmployeesArray.push(item.Title);
                        $("#EmployeeField").append("<option value='"+item.Title+"'>"+item.Title+"</option>");     
                }                        
                }           
            }   
        });
```

Comment: Hi I Tired your code above, it is not fetching all the names in the array it is fetching only 6 names

Comment: Which array are you talking about?

Comment: Can you explain why you have used 2 loops here?

Comment: The problem that i am facing is when i use top =1500 there are more than 5 arrays, i get the first array values how do i get all the array values?

Comment: You have used top=500 in your query and not top=1500. You are running 1 loop on "allEmployeeNames" and 1 loop on "employee.Should_x0020_Cost_x0020_Modeler.results" . Why are you doing this? Can you share the resulting array you are getting from the rest call?

Comment: Is this "Should_x0020_Cost_x0020_Modeler" people picker field is allowing multiple selections??

Comment: Yes, it is multiple selections. I will share the result

Answer (score 0):

You incorrectly use your jquery ajax function `getAllEmployeeNames`. You shouldn't use `async: false` for the modern web. Correct one:

```
function getAllEmployeeNames() {
    return $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Should Cost Projects')/items?$select=Should_x0020_Cost_x0020_Modeler/Title&$expand=Should_x0020_Cost_x0020_Modeler/Id&$top=500",
        type: "GET",
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        }
    })
    .then(function(data){
        return data.d.results;
    })
    .fail(function(err){
        console.log(err);
        alert('error');
    });
}
```

then you can filter unique names using array (that one option):

```
getAllEmployeeNames()
    .then(function(results){
        var uniqueNames = [];

        results.forEach(function(employee){
            employee.Should_x0020_Cost_x0020_Modeler.results.forEach(function(name){
                if(uniqueNames.indexOf(name) === -1) {
                    uniqueNames.push(name)
                }
            })
        })

        // now you have array with unique names
        // add it to dropdown here
    })
```

Comment: The problem that i am facing is when i use top =1500 there are more than 5 arrays, i get the first array values how do i get all the array values?

Answer (score 0):

Using the code below to remove the duplicates options of the dropdown list.

```
$("#EmployeeField option").each(function() {
        $(this).siblings('[value="'+ $(this).val() +'"]').remove();
});
```

Comment: This is not working. As i am fetching 5000 top employee name, it does not remove the duplicate.

Comment: Could you help me regarding this

Comment: The problem that i am facing is when i use top =1500 there are more than 5 arrays, i get the first array values how do i get all the array values?

Answer (score 0):

Replace this part of code

```
$(allEmployeeNames).each(function() {
    $(this).siblings('[value="'+ $(this).val() +'"]').remove();
});
```

with

```
var uniqueEmployeeNames = [];
$(allEmployeeNames).each(employee.Should_x0020_Cost_x0020_Modeler.results, function(i, el){
    if($.inArray(el, uniqueNames) === -1) uniqueEmployeeNames.push(el);
});
```

Comment: it did not work

Answer (score 0):

May be below code will help you

First of all get all data and bind it to drop-down list as you can see below

This is HTML for reference

```
<div>
    <select id="ddlEmployee">
        <option value="0">select user</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Below is Js Code

```
 function getDataREST(requestUrl, successFun, failFun){
   $.ajax({
      url: requestUrl,
      type: "GET",
      async:false,
      headers: {
          "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
      },
      success: function (data) {
          successFun(data)
      },
      error: function (data) {
         failFun(data)
      }
   });
}
function bindEmployeetoDDL(){
    var addItemUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('UserLists')/items?$select=Id, Title,UserName/Id,UserName/Title&$expand=UserName&$top=2000" 
    getDataREST(addItemUrl, function (data){
        if(data && data.d.results.length > 0)
        {
            for(i=0;i<data.d.results.length;i++){
                 $("#ddlEmployee").append("<option value='"+data.d.results[i].UserName.Id+"'>"+data.d.results[i].UserName.Title+"</option>");
            }
            //removeDuplicateByValue()
            removeDuplicateByText()
        }
    }, function (error){
        console.log("Error while getting employee", Error)
    });
}
```

After successfully data bind to drop-down one of below method to remove duplicate entry from drop-down options

```
//This will be remove duplicate options by value
function removeDuplicateByValue()
{
    $("#ddlEmployee Option").each(function() {
        $(this).siblings('[value="'+ $(this).val() +'"]').remove();
    });
}

//This will be remove duplicate options by text
function removeDuplicateByText()
{
    $("#ddlEmployee Option").each(function() {
        $(this).siblings(':contains('+ $(this).text() +')').remove();
    });
}
```